# How to access TileList item index in a custom Item Renderer

Tags: apache-flex

```
  <mx:itemRenderer>   
     <mx:Component>   
       <mx:Canvas> 
         <mx:Image source="{outerDocument.get_img()}" scaleContent="false" />   
       </mx:Canvas>   
     </mx:Component>   
  </mx:itemRenderer>
```

So if I wanted to pass the index of the list item being rendered to get_img as a parameter,  how would that be done. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just an update - Its a lot faster to use a BitmapAsset as the source as opposed to encoder.encode.  (No flicker).  But then it has to be set up like the following. (i.e. the BitmapAsset needs to be recreated each time  the ItemRenderer has to re-render - don't ask me why.):

```
  <mx:Script>
    <![CDATA[

  private var bmd_arr:Array = new Array();

  private function InitImgList():void  {      
    var arr:Array = new Array();
    var r:Rectangle = new Rectangle(0,0,100,20);            
    var pt:Point = new Point(0,0);
    for (r.x=0; r.x<img.width; r.x+=100) {
      var bmd:BitmapData = new BitmapData(100,20,false,0);      
      bmd.copyPixels(Bitmap(img.content).bitmapData,r,pt);  
      bmd_arr.push(bmd);            
      var obj:Object = {label:"",n:bmd_arr.length-1};         
      arr.push(obj);
    }       
    ImgList.dataProvider = arr;
  }

  public function get_img(n:int):BitmapAsset {
    return new BitmapAsset(bmd_arr[n]);   
  }

    ]]>
  </mx:Script>

  <mx:itemRenderer>   
     <mx:Component>   
     <mx:Canvas> 
         <mx:Image x="2" source="{outerDocument.get_img(data.n)}" scaleContent="false" />   
       </mx:Canvas>   
     </mx:Component>   
  </mx:itemRenderer>   


</mx:TileList>
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason I needed the index, is that I was constructing a series of images, one for each cell, by iterating throught a master image (like a Windows ImageList) and taking a portion of the master image for each cell.  I needed the index so that when a cell rendering was refreshed, it always went to the correct location in the master image.  But I found I could create a ByteArray of each subimage and make it a field in each object in the DataProvider.  Anyway, no longer need the "index":

```
<mx:TileList id="ImgList" height="{parent.height-45}" width="226" 
  maxColumns="2" rowHeight="24" columnWidth="104" x="0" y="45" 
  creationComplete="{InitImgList()}"    
>    
  <mx:Script>
    <![CDATA[

      private function InitImgList():void  {      
        var arr:Array = new Array();
        var r:Rectangle = new Rectangle(0,0,100,20);            
        var pt:Point = new Point(0,0);
        var encoder:PNGEncoder = new PNGEncoder();
        for (r.x=0; r.x<img.width; r.x+=100) {
          var bmd:BitmapData = new BitmapData(100,20,true,0);   
          bmd.copyPixels(Bitmap(img.content).bitmapData,r,pt);  
          var obj:Object = {label:"", source:encoder.encode(bmd)}         
          arr.push(obj);
        }       
        ImgList.dataProvider = arr;
      }

    ]]>
  </mx:Script>

  <mx:itemRenderer>   
     <mx:Component>   
         <mx:Canvas> 
         <mx:Image source="{data.source}" scaleContent="false" />   
       </mx:Canvas>   
     </mx:Component>   
  </mx:itemRenderer>   


</mx:TileList>
```